# Reduce the size of an image (200*150 to 20 *15)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images

I want to reduce the size of an image from 200*150 to 20*15.

But when I do that in Photoshop, the image looks blurred. Is there any way we can reduce the size without this happening?
Do i have do anything with the resolution...

Comment: you may wish to try slightly sharpening your image after the resize, a touch of sharpening after shrinking usually helps the crispness of photos -- but don't go overboard, over-sharpening becomes painful quickly.

Comment: 20*15 is incredibly small. I assume you're making an icon. You really can't just shrink an image down to that size and expect it to be legible. Images of that size are typically hand drawn to accommodate that tiny resolution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reducing the size of an image will *necessarily* cause the loss of some resolution. The trick lies in sharpening the resulting image enough that it looks good, but not so much that it begins to pixellate.

Fortunately, you're already using Photoshop, and it really does come close to working miracles sometimes. Here's a [blog post](http://www.photoshopsupport.com/tutorials/jennifer/bicubic.html) that explains how to do *exactly* what you've asked for.

> When you want to reduce an image go to the Image > Image Size menu. Click on Resample Image and choose **Bicubic Sharper** from the drop-down menu. This is the best setting for making sure that an image doesn't blur. The example photo of the flower started at 2,000 pixels across. I stepped it down to 250, and then again to 125 with almost no loss of sharpness. For enlarging an image select Bicubic Smoother.

Answer (score -1):

You can do the same in MS Paint. In the Image -> Stretch/Skew menu option, give 10% 10% on both Horizontal and vertical.

Comment: Yeah, no. That's not the same as Photoshop. It's also not going to sharpen the image, or make it look halfway decent at all, when you resize it.

Comment: considering the size to be reduced is to 20x15, does the image quality matter at all? :-)

Comment: it's not about the quality .. once you reduce the size the image will be blurred because of the compression of the pixels.. So we need something better.